# Convert non-zero image pixels to row-column coordinates and save the output to workspace

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm having difficulties converting image pixels to coordinates and making them appear in my MATLAB workspace. For example, I have the image with pixel values as below (it's a binary image of size 4x4):

```
0 0 0 0

0 1 1 0

0 1 1 0 

0 0 0 0
```

After getting the pixels, I want to read each value and if they're not equal to zero (which means 1), I want to read the coordinates of that value and save them in to my MATLAB workspace.  For example, this is the idea that I thought of:

```
[x,y] = size(image)
for i=1:x
   for j=1:y
       if (image(i,j)~=0)
       ....
```

However, I am stuck. Can anyone give any suggestion on how to read the coordinates of the non-zero values and save them to my workspace?

Specifically, my expected result in the workspace:

```
2 2

2 3

3 2

3 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it with loops is probably not the most efficient way to do what you ask.  Instead, use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).  `find` determines the locations in a vector or matrix that are non-zero.  In your case, all you have to do is:

```
[row,col] = find(image);
```

`row` and `col` would contain the row and column locations of the non-zero elements in your binary image.  Therefore, with your example:

```
b = [0 0 0 0;
     0 1 1 0;
     0 1 1 0;
     0 0 0 0];
```

We get:

```
>> disp([row, col]);

 2     2
 3     2
 2     3
 3     3
```

However, you'll see that the locations are not in the order you expect.  This is because the locations are displayed **in column-major** order, meaning that the columns are traversed first.  In your example, you are displaying them in row-major order.  If you'd like to maintain this order, you would sort the results by the row coordinate:

```
>> sortrows([row, col])

ans =

     2     2
     2     3
     3     2
     3     3
```

---

However, if you really really really really... I mean really... want to use `for` loops, what you would do is keep two separate arrays that are initially empty, then loop through each pixel and determine whether it's non-zero.  If it is, then you would add the `x` and `y` locations to these two separate arrays.

As such, you would do this:

```
row = []; col = [];
[x,y] = size(image);
for i=1:x
   for j=1:y
       if (image(i,j)~=0)
           row = [row; i]; %// Concatenate row and column location if non-zero
           col = [col; j];
       end
   end
end
```

This should give you the same results as `find`.

Comment: the idea of using find is really helpful since my image are big in size, using loops could be my last option. thank you!

Comment: @syakey - My pleasure, and I'm glad you found my answer useful.  Good luck!

Comment: Is it possible to get row and col in an array with value nx2?

Comment: @syakey - `array = [row, col];`

Answer (score 1):

you can use meshgrid() to collect those coordinates. The function generates two outputs, first being x coordinates, second being y coordinates. you'd go like this:

```
[xcoord ycoord] = meshgrid( 1:x_size, 1:y_size);

zeros_coordsx = xcoord( image == 0);
zeros_coordsy = ycoord( image == 0);
```

this is way faster that nested looping and keeps you within matlab's natural vector operation space... these two outputs are in sync,meaning that

```
image( zeros_coordsy(1), zeros_coordsx(1))
```

is one of the zeros on the image

Comment: You should probably change that to `image ~= 0` as the OP is looking for all non-zero coordinates.  Also, would obtaining a `meshgrid` of coordinates, then indexing into each dimension of coordinates be faster than using `find`?  Also, this seems a bit unnecessary in terms of memory complexity.  You are essentially occupying `2N` more doubles in memory to do what you're asking, where `N` is the total size of the image.

Comment: There's no reason why this would be faster than find. The method came to my mind as I often used it when I needed to calculate some values based on the coordinates, like texture generation. Old habits, nothing more profound :). Your comment is 100% correct, find() does the job just fine. 

What's worth noting, though is that meshgrid() method works with more dimensions - even though it is not important in the discussion. :)

Comment: Aha, true enough with `meshgrid`.  However, if you wanted to extend `find` to multiple dimensions, you could simply obtain the column-major linear indices, then invoke an `ind2sub` call... but yes, that's besides the point :).  I do like the alternative method however, and it's certainly the right way to go with regards to things like texture generation.  I'll give you a +1.